# Spacy NER output, How to save ent.label,ent.text?

Tags: spacy

I am using this code:

```
"
c=[]
for i, j in article.iterrows():
c.append(j)
d=[]
for i in c:
e={}
e['Urls']=(i[0])
a = str(i[2])
doc = ner(a)
for ent in doc.ents:
e[ent.label_]=(ent.text)
d.append(e)
"
```

My output looks something like this:

```
[{'Urls': 'https://somewebsite.com',
'Fruit': 'Apple',
'Fruit_colour': 'Red'},
{'Urls': 'Urls': 'https://some_other_website.com/',
'Fruit': 'Papaya',
'Fruit_Colour': 'Yellow'}
```

I have multiple values fruit , Desire output looks like:
{'Urls': 'https://somewebsite.com'
'Fruit': 'Apple',
'Fruit': 'orange',
'Fruit': 'watermelon',
'Fruit_colour': 'Red',
'Fruit_colour': 'orange',
'Fruit_colour': 'Green'}

```
{'Urls': 'Urls': 'https://some_other_website.com/',
'Fruit': 'Papaya',
'Fruit': 'Peach',
'Fruit':  Mango'
'Fruit_Colour': 'Yellow',
'Fruit_Colour': 'Yellow
'Fruit_Colour': 'Green'}
```

Your help and time is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to have lost its indentation, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to save multiple values in a single key. You can use a `defaultdict` with `list`s for that.

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

doc = ... get it from spaCy ...

for ent in doc.ents:
    out[ent.label_].append(ent.text)
print(out)
```